# scala parsing combinators force parsers ordering

Tags: scala, parsing

assume two parsers: `p` & `q`.
now, given the following code:

```
val p1 = p | q
val p2 = "$" ~> p1 <~ "$"
```

something weird is happening. assume some string: `val input = "..."`

```
parseAll(p1, input)
```

succeeds with `p`'s parsing result, but:

```
parseAll(p2, "$" + input +"$")
```

succeeds with `q`'s parsing result.
the order is important. I only want to try `q` after `p` failed.

is there any way I can force the parser to evaluate `p` before `q`?

### EDIT:

after checking the docs more carefully:

> `p | q` succeeds if `p` succeeds or `q` succeeds.
>   Note that `q` is only tried if `p`s failure is non-fatal (i.e., back-tracking is allowed).

so my code should work.
so I tried reproducing with a simple example (my original code is too use case specific and most of it not relevant for here). but didn't quite succeed. instead, I managed to come up with a parser that fails when it should succeed. shown in the following REPL session:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.7 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_66).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import scala.util.parsing.combinator._
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._

scala> object MyParser extends RegexParsers {
     |   val xyz = "xyz".r ^^ { case s => Right(s) }
     |   val any = "\\S+".r ^^ { case s => Left(s) }
     |   val either: Parser[Either[String,String]] = xyz | any
     |   val wrapped = "$" ~> either <~ "$"
     |   def parseMeATest1(input: String) = parseAll(either, input) match {
     |     case Success(Right(s),_) => println(s"right: $s")
     |     case Success(Left(s),_) => println(s"left: $s")
     |     case NoSuccess(msg, _) => println(msg)
     |   }
     |   def parseMeATest2(input: String) = parseAll(wrapped, input) match {
     |     case Success(Right(s),_) => println(s"right: $s")
     |     case Success(Left(s),_) => println(s"left: $s")
     |     case NoSuccess(msg, _) => println(msg)
     |   }
     | }
defined object MyParser

scala> MyParser.parseMeATest1("xyz")
right: xyz

scala> MyParser.parseMeATest1("zzz")
left: zzz

scala> MyParser.parseMeATest2("$xyz$")
right: xyz

scala> MyParser.parseMeATest2("$zzz$")
`$' expected but end of source found
```

So, am I missing something here<s>, or this a bug with scala parsing combinators</s>?

### SOLVED:

problem was that `p` parser consumed the trailing `$` character, causing overall failure, but since backtracking is used, `q` which does not consume the `$` character completed successfully.

Comment: Post your solution as an answer and accept it? :)

Comment: But it's not really a solution. The question asks about general parsers (`p`,`q`). But I had a bug in the parser itself, not in the combinator which operated on the parser...

Comment: Do you have example parsers for (`p`, `q`) that reproduce the problem?

Comment: @jkinkead `val p = """\S*""".r` for example...

Comment: What would `q` be in that case? Also, doesn't that repeat the problem of consuming the closing `$`?

Comment: @jkinkead `q` could b anything that accepts the input. It does not matter (`.*` for example). And consuming the trailing `$` in `p` (given that `p` won't backtrack after trying to accept the largest token it could) was in fact the problem.

Comment: So, this doesn't work for a similar reason to the problem you had before: The `p` pattern matches up through `$`, and is considered a successful parse so far. In order to support the feature you want, the parse engine would have to be integrated into the internals of the regex `Parser` instance. To fix this style of issue, you can either require whitespace around the `$`, or use a zero-width lookahead in your regex: `val p = """\S*(?=\$)"""`

Comment: sounds about right :)